# web scraping - Changing Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that Extract data from web and print it in a specific sheet `Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(x, x)` in excel , the code works perfectly but the problem is  :

**The extract is only for one value** see `If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = "k20442"`

What I want is to change `k20442` with for e.g :

```
Set Plage = Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
count = 1
For Each Cell In Plage
MPNum = Cell.Value
count = count + 1
```

and this line becomes like this `If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value =  MPNum`

which mean when I run the code it makes the search using the values which are located here  `Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)` and print data in sheet 1

```
Option Explicit

Sub extrt()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim IE As Object, elemCollection As Object
    Dim itm As IHTMLElement, oHtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long
    Dim doc, tags, tagx, i, ele

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ".do?clearBackList=true&CMH_NO_STORING_fromMenu=true"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        'we ensure that the web Page is loaded completely
        Set itm = .document.getElementsByName("searchById")(0)
        If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = "k20442"
        Set doc = .document

        Set tags = .document.getElementsByTagName("input")

        For Each tagx In tags
            If tagx.src = "http:/mage/button_search.gif" Then tagx.Click
        Next

        'On Error Resume Next  'disable error handling during troubleshooting

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .document.body.innerHTML

    End With

    Set elemCollection = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("TableContent")

    Debug.Print elemCollection.Length
    Debug.Print oHtml.body.innerHTML

    Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:AK500").ClearContents

    i = 1
    For Each ele In elemCollection(4).getElementsByTagName("TD")
        Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(4, i) = ele.innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next

    i = 1
    For Each ele In elemCollection(1).getElementsByTagName("TD")
        Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(6, i) = ele.innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next

    For t = 0 To (elemCollection.Length - 1)
        For r = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                Sheets("Feuil1").Cells(r + 2, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        DoEvents
        Next r
    Next t


    IE.Quit

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

the line of the search that needed to be modified is this

```
 If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = "k20442"
```

and the result  is like this just for one variable in sheet1
[image]

and the table of the other values that I want to use  them for my search are located in sheet2

[image]

As libraries I'm using :

**1- Microsoft HTML Object Library**

**2-Microsoft Internet Control**

**3-Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

Can Anyone light me in solving this ?

Comment: 1st think I notice (once I properly indented your code): **None of your `With` statements are doing a thing since you're using them incorrectly.**  ...correction, 2 lines are ok: `.Visible = True` and the next one.  Notice how they have a `.` dot where it should be replaced with the object referenced in their `With`?

Comment: If you switch to a different worksheet and then run your code, your ranges will not be referring to *that*.  A statement needs to begins with a dot to reference the `With`.  Also, it's strange to keep end & re-opening the same `With` statements.

Comment: you mean the first 'With IE' better to be delated and change 'IE.visible True' ?

Comment: exactly.   `With blah`  `.something`  `End With`  is the same as `blah.someting`.

Comment: It's more like perfermance ,Ok I see I'm gonna trying to modify that  but any idea on changing Variable  ?

Comment: another example of something weird:  `With ws` `Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1:AK500").ClearContents` `End With`... #1 ws isn't doing anything. #2 if you changed it to `.Sheets("F....` is still doesn't make sense since the `With` & `End With` statements take much more space than just simply using `ws.Sheets("F...`

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do.  Could you add an example of what the sheet should look like after it's done

Comment: ...also, which libraries (references) have you added?

Comment: Yes , I know I need to revise the whole code later  to simplify it , Ok i will show you the result I'm modifying the question for you

Comment: Also the URLs you're loading is invalid (`http:/mage/button_search.gif`).  It's difficult to help you without knowing what's going in, and what's supposed to come out.  I suppose it's mainly this part of the explanation that doesn't make sense:  `I want to put the Variable that I want to loop for in a sheet and run the macro to Extract all the data of those Variable in another sheet `

Comment: Also, you haven't declared all of your variables.  Put `Option Explicit` at the top of this (and every) module (forever) to help you identify these kinda of problems.

Comment: the url is for our entreprise which is local you can't access and the button contains port Number which confidential " Airbus policy"

Comment: Can't say for sure but likely because there are a number of things in you question that should have been addressed before it was posted, such as formatting and examples.  See "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]" and also these [tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).  It's important to read the FAQ's when posting, and also to do some research ahead of time.  But don't sweat the downvote, they can always get retracted when a question is edited;  rules are strict on this site for a reason, and there's a ;learning curve getting used to them :)

Comment: @ashleedawg I have a lot of people standing and waiting for me to complet  this in airbus site I don't have too much Time but Thank you for the help , I'm revising this  just I need to solve the main question

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm going to replace the code in your question with a better formatting version, `With` statements fixed, etc?  Is that okay?  (I'm asking because it's more than just indents like before.)

Comment: Neither one was me :-) I'll be a couple mins with the code. I still am not clear on what you're trying to do so this won't fix that, it's just making the question more clear.

Comment: haha :-) it's ok I deserve that , So I have a Table located in sheet2 cointains Values and I want is to Ectract Data for each Value in sheet2 in the Table exactly and print it in sheet 1 , is this much more clear ?

Comment: back to the `with ws` for a sec:  there's no statement like `Set ws = ..` telling ws what it is, so that's reason #3 they were serving no purpose.

Comment: Ok Sir  , Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet and Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook

Comment: any ideas in solving this  :-)

Comment: I'm afraid that using `activesheet` is still pointless.:-)  ActiveSheet is whatever the currently selected worksheet is, which is what ranges will refer to by default if a worksheet isn't specified.

Comment: Nope - still no idea what you're trying to do.  Earlier i asked about this statement: `I want to put the Variable that I want to loop for in a sheet and run macro to Extract all the data of those Variable in another sheet`(maybe rephrasing it would help) and I also suggested some links with more info for you.  Now I'm confused by the screenshots.  Are you properly getting the data loaded from the web, and now you just want to process the data from one sheet onto a another??  If that's the case, you need to remove all mention of web scraping from the code & question since that's not he problem.

Comment: It's ok with Activesheet because have the button in that sheet but  changing it with sheets("Feuil1")  is better I think   to prevent error and mis-selection

Comment: Ok , the code works fine, and those data are correct from the web , I just   need to make multiple search on alot of value not just 1 as you see in my question , and the values are located in sheet 2 .... I taged Html and webscrapping  to prevent solution that could Impact my code

Comment: forget about activesheet for now.  **[Click here and read this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** : the goal is to ***remove*** (minimize) code, not to add to it.

Comment: Oh my goodness.   What a waste of time. **Read all of these links, top to bottom** [tour] AND [mcve] AND [ask] AND [help/on-topic], and then edit your entire question or else delete ir and post a new one  If you're not having an issue with Web Scraping don't mention Web Scraping.  The ONLY code you include should be just enough to demonstrate the part you're struggling with.

Comment: Done, hope this will change your opinion :-)

Comment: @ashleedawg  xD be cool :-) , from Now on I'm gonna follow those steps like I did Now , I modifed the solution , Thank you for your time and your help , Have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to find the solution  , I created  this

```
Dim MPNum As Variant 
Dim lastRow As Variant
Dim d As Long
Dim f As Variant 
lastRow = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  
d = 0
For Each f In Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
MPNum = f
    d = d + 1
Next f
```

and I changed this line :

```
If Not itm Is Nothing Then itm.Value = MPNum
```

So until here the code works fine perfectly :)  and makes multiple search